# Advice wanted on getting rid of loops

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have written a program that works with the 3n + 1 problem (aka "wondrous numbers" and various other things).  But it has a double loop.  How could I vectorize it?

the code is

```
count <- vector("numeric", 100000)
L <- length(count)

for (i in 1:L)
{
x <- i
   while (x > 1)
   {
   if (round(x/2) == x/2) 
     {
     x <- x/2
     count[i] <- count[i] + 1 
     } else
     {
     x <- 3*x + 1
     count[i] <- count[i] + 1
     }
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to steal this for an example of embarrassingly parallel process in R! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you need to iterate on values of `x` you can't really vectorize this. At some point, R has to work on each value of x separately and in turn. You might be able to run the computations on separate CPU cores to speed things up, perhaps using `foreach` in the package of the same name.

Otherwise, (and this is just hiding the loop from you), wrap the main body of your loop as a function, e.g.:

```
wonderous <- function(n) {
    count <- 0
    while(n > 1) {
        if(isTRUE(all.equal(n %% 2, 0))) {
            n <- n / 2
        } else {
            n <- (3*n) + 1
        }
        count <- count + 1
    }
    return(count)
}
```

and then you can use `sapply()` to run the function on a set of numbers:

```
> sapply(1:50, wonderous)
 [1]   0   1   7   2   5   8  16   3  19   6  14   9   9  17  17
[16]   4  12  20  20   7   7  15  15  10  23  10 111  18  18  18
[31] 106   5  26  13  13  21  21  21  34   8 109   8  29  16  16
[46]  16 104  11  24  24
```

Or you can use `Vectorize` to return a vectorized version of `wonderous` which is itself a function that hides even more of this from you:

```
> wonderousV <- Vectorize(wonderous)
> wonderousV(1:50)
 [1]   0   1   7   2   5   8  16   3  19   6  14   9   9  17  17
[16]   4  12  20  20   7   7  15  15  10  23  10 111  18  18  18
[31] 106   5  26  13  13  21  21  21  34   8 109   8  29  16  16
[46]  16 104  11  24  24
```

<strike>I think that is about as far as you can get with standard R tools at the moment.</strike>@Martin Morgan shows you can do a lot better than this with an ingenious take on solving the problem that **does** used R's vectorised abilities.

Comment: That's how I would do it (but with snowfall package for parallel execution).

Answer (score 9):

I turned this 'inside-out' by creating a vector x where the ith element is the value after each iteration of the algorithm. The result is relatively intelligible as

```
f1 <- function(L) {
    x <- seq_len(L)
    count <- integer(L)
    while (any(i <- x > 1)) {
        count[i] <- count[i] + 1L
        x <- ifelse(round(x/2) == x/2, x / 2, 3 * x + 1) * i
    }
    count
}
```

This can be optimized to (a) track only those values still in play (via idx) and (b) avoid unnecessary operations, e.g., ifelse evaluates both arguments for all values of x, x/2 evaluated twice.

```
f2 <- function(L) {
    idx <- x <- seq_len(L)
    count <- integer(L)
    while (length(x)) {
        ix <- x > 1
        x <- x[ix]
        idx <- idx[ix]
        count[idx] <- count[idx] + 1L
        i <- as.logical(x %% 2)
        x[i] <- 3 * x[i] + 1
        i <- !i
        x[i] <- x[i] / 2
    }
    count
}
```

with f0 the original function, I have

```
> L <- 10000
> system.time(ans0 <- f0(L))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.785   0.000   7.812 
> system.time(ans1 <- f1(L))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.738   0.000   1.741 
> identical(ans0, ans1)
[1] TRUE
> system.time(ans2 <- f2(L))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.301   0.000   0.301 
> identical(ans1, ans2)
[1] TRUE
```

A tweak is to update odd values to 3 * x[i] + 1 and then do the division by two unconditionally

```
x[i] <- 3 * x[i] + 1
count[idx[i]] <- count[idx[i]] + 1L
x <- x / 2
count[idx] <- count[idx] + 1
```

With this as f3 (not sure why f2 is slower this morning!) I get

```
> system.time(ans2 <- f2(L))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.36    0.00    0.36 
> system.time(ans3 <- f3(L))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.201   0.003   0.206 
> identical(ans2, ans3)
[1] TRUE
```

It seems like larger steps can be taken at the divide-by-two stage, e.g., 8 is 2^3 so we could take 3 steps (add 3 to count) and be finished, 20 is 2^2 * 5 so we could take two steps and enter the next iteration at 5. Implementations?

Answer (score 2):

A different approach recognizes that one frequently revisits low numbers, so why not remember them and save the re-calculation cost?

```
memo_f <- function() {
    e <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
    e[["1"]] <- 0L
    f <- function(x) {
        k <- as.character(x)
        if (!exists(k, envir=e))
            e[[k]] <- 1L + if (x %% 2) f(3L * x + 1L) else f(x / 2L)
        e[[k]]
    }
    f
}
```

which gives

```
> L <- 100
> vals <- seq_len(L)
> system.time({ f <- memo_f(); memo1 <- sapply(vals, f) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.018   0.000   0.019 
> system.time(won <- sapply(vals, wonderous))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.921   0.005   0.930 
> all.equal(memo1, won) ## integer vs. numeric
[1] TRUE
```

This might not parallelize well, but then maybe that's not necessary with the 50x speedup? Also the recursion might get too deep, but the recursion could be written as a loop (which is probably faster, anyway).